# Integration of Airtel Money API into our website

Tags: api, airtelmoney

We have an website that's currently operating in beta and is aimed at the East African market.  We want to integrate Airtel Money into the site.  However, i haven't found any information about:

- how to register for the service
- how to integrate into our website.

I would imagine there is some global Airtel Money api that we need to apply for access for and imagine also that there is a test/sandbox version of the api and a production version as well.

Does anyone know how we would go about registering for this service?

I've seen that there are a number of api integrators out there like Jenga or Pesapal.  However, we would prefer to integrate directory with the telco's in order to reduce costs and minimise the potential points of failure.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry boss,
Those guys AFAIK have not released a public api. You need to reverse engineer their airtel money apk to find out how they do it. In the mean time you are stuck with middlemen like `easypay`

Comment: thanks. We are going to use other payment gateways to help with this. That should simplify things anyway